# How to assign a static hostname or IP-Address to Amazon ec2 machine?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon EC2 Machine, i am having running HDP on it with Hadoop and some other big data tools like hive, 
hbase, 
pig.

I use the machine name like ec2.1.1.1compute-1.amazonaws.com for Host Name, but when i reboot my machine its IP-Address get changed , so need to change Host Name.

So how can i use a simple static name to resolved IP-Address of machine even my IP get changed.

#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#

#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#

### #

#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like [this](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install ddclient and dynamically assign a hostname using [dynamic DNS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS). There might be a lag between boot and propagation of the name through DNS, depending on the provider you choose. There are many free services available.

While an EC2 instance can have a single Elastic IP associated with it for free, [you will be nominally charged when it is not in use](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/#elastic-ip).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use what Amazon calls an Elastic IP address. These are fixed IP addresses you can assign to your running EC2 instances. Last time I checked there was a small charge for using Elastic IPs, and you were limited to 5 Elastic IPs per account, so use sparingly.

You may need to write a small script to automatically assign your Elastic IP, which you execute as "User Data" when you boot your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign it an Elastic IP. This IP will remain associated with the instance until the instance is terminated.

Comment: Unfortunately you only get one free elastic IP :[